# Запись в файл структуры из QVector и последующее чтение

Tags: c++, qt, vector, сериализация, binary-file

У меня вектор содержит структуры с данными, и нужно записать эти данные в двоичный файл. После чего считать.
Не пойму, как это сделать правильно.

```
struct TestMessage
{
    short number=10;            
    int type=101;

} __attribute__((packed));
TestMessage message;


QVector<TestMessage> vec;
QVector<TestMessage> vec2;

QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &out, const TestMessage &any)
{
    out << any.number;
    out << any.type;
    return out;
}
QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &in, TestMessage &any)
{
    in >> any.number;//cannot bind packed field '...number' to qint32& aka int&
    in >> any.type;//cannot bind packed field '...type' to qint16& aka short&
    return in;
}
void read()
{
    vec.push_back(message);
        
    QFile file("/home/testwrite.bat");
    file.open(QIODevice::Append)
    QDataStream out(&file);
    out << vec[0];
    file.close();



  QDataStream in(&file);
  if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
      in >> vec2[0];
      qDebug() << vec2[0].number;
};
};
```

Comment: А разве у класса ```QFile``` существует функция, способная принять Ваш ```TestMessage``` ?

Comment: Используйте QDataStream https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html

Comment: по-простому — `file.write((const char*)vec[i], sizeof(TestMessage))`, но здесь есть несколько способов прострелить себе ногу…

Comment: `in >> (short&)any.number;` `in >> (int&)any.type;`